# Linux - named pipes - role of mode in mknod

Tags: linux, named-pipes

I am trying to understand how I can do IPC with named pipes in Linux. I found a sample code at this [link](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node18.html).

Can someone please tell what is role of the mode argument in `mknod()` ? I am particularly interested in the permissions part. Why is a bitwise OR done for that argument ? How is the argument used once the named pipe is created ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read carefully [mknod(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mknod.2.html) man page (e.g. type `man 2 mknod` in a terminal).

> ```
>    The mode argument specifies both the permissions to use and the type
>    of node to be created.  It should be a combination (using bitwise OR)
>    of one of the file types listed below and the permissions for the new
>    node.
> ```

BTW, you might -and probably should- use [mkfifo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html) instead (or, in a shell script or terminal, the [mkfifo(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mkfifo.1.html) command).

The permissions are mostly useful for processes which are [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)-ing an already existing named pipe.

<sup>With appropriate permission settings, you could restrict the usage of a FIFO to e.g. only the members of some given group.</sup>

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [capabiities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html), and about [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid).

Comment: Since the permissions are based on ACL (user, group, other), does this mean in linux, programs can be configured to receive IPC from programs running in different users (uids) ?